# realloc not appearing to work for pointers to pointers

Tags: c, realloc

When I try to use `realloc` for the outer pointer of pointers, the memory address keeps changing even though I set it back to the original pointer.

Here is the code below. The `realloc` is in the `read_list` function. I tried reproducing the issue by just using a barebones pointer to pointer and reallocating, and it worked, so the error might be elsewhere, but I cannot pinpoint it, so all of the code is included.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_MEM 32

int read_list(char **, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **dict;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR]: Usage is \"%s <dict> <list>\"\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    dict = malloc(INIT_MEM);
    if (read_list(dict, argv[1])) return(1);
    printf("&dict[0]: %d\n", &dict[0]);

    return(0);
}

int read_list(char **dest, char *file_name)
{
    FILE *stream; /* list of words file */
    char ch; /* current char read */
    int i, j, k, start, read_mode; /* start: file position beginning of each line; see initializations for rest */
    int total_memory; /* COUNTS MEMORY */
    int i_mem = INIT_MEM; /* initial memory */

    stream = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR]: Invalid input file!");
        return(1);
    }

    i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, total_memory = 0; /* i: size counter; j = word counter; k = ch counter */
    read_mode = 1; /* 1: true; 0: false */ 
    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) { /* read in each characters */
        if (ch == '\n') { /* after reaching end of line */
            if (read_mode) { /* if in read-mode */
                while (total_memory >= i_mem) { /* allocate more memory for dest if hit upper limit */
                    i_mem *= 2; /* double the memory size */
                    printf("IN_TM_BEFORE@%d= &dest[0]: %d\n", i_mem, &dest[0]);
                    dest = realloc(dest, i_mem); /* allocate increased memory into dest */  
                    printf("IN_TM_AFTER@%d= &dest[0]: %d\n", i_mem, &dest[0]);
                    /* printf("i_mem:%d\n", i_mem); =================== */
                    if (dest == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR]: Memory reallocation failed!\n");
                        return(1);
                    }
                }
                dest[j] = malloc(i); /* allocate string with i, the size of word*/
                total_memory += i + 1; /* increase allocated memory mount by size + 1 to account for pointer*/
                read_mode = 0; /* turn to transfer mode */
                fseek(stream, start - 1, SEEK_SET); /* move back to start of word to transfer */
            } else {
                i = 0, k = 0; /* reset */
                read_mode = 1; /* go to read mode */
                j++; /* allow recording for next word */
            }
        }
        else {
            if (read_mode) { /* determine length of string */
                if (i == 0) start = ftell(stream); /* record start of word for transfer mode */
                i++; /* count characters in word */
            } else { /* record string */
                dest[j][k++] = ch;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("FINAL: &dest[0]: %d\n", &dest[0]);

    return(0);
}
```

=============================== dict.txt ===============================

```
flyer
go
crabulus
prose
humperdoodle
moo
dragon
enderman
yellow
abonobo
```

I've already tried changing the outer pointer (pointer pointing to the pointers) to a size of 5000 and removing `realloc` and the memory addresses are fine, but when I include `realloc`, the issue arises.

When I `realloc`, I get this result:

```
IN_TM_BEFORE@64= &dest[0]: 35962896
IN_TM_AFTER@64= &dest[0]: 35963690
IN_TM_BEFORE@128= &dest[0]: 35963690
IN_TM_AFTER@128= &dest[0]: 35963888
FINAL: &dest[0]: 35963888
&dict[0]: 35962896
```

Which appears to imply that after I `realloc`, the pointer is not being set back to `dest`, even though I did `dest = realloc(dest, i_mem);`

Comment: `realloc` returns a different pointer then the original. What is your question? Also you should pass the size you want to realloc `realloc(dest, sizeof(char*) * i_mam)` and `dict = malloc(sizeof(char*) * INIIT_MEM)`, not the count of elements only! And values to function are passed by value, not by reference in C, so `read_list` _does not_ modify `dict` value in main.

Comment: I want it to be set back to the original pointer <code>dest</code>. Sorry, wasn’t clear. The problem that’s happening right now is that because the pointer changes, the pointer <code>dest</code> lacks data outside the function because it points to the original location with INIT_MAX memory allocated.

Comment: If you realloc the pointer, the pointer _has to_ be able change. So, you should modify the pointer inside `main`, not modify how your function works so it doesn't need to change it's value...

Comment: Isn’t sizeof(char *) just 1 because you sizeof a pointer to a memory location, which is just 1? Also I’m passing a pointer so read_list should modify dict. At least when I tried more basic functions.

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` is size of an address. `sizeof(char*)` may be ex. `4` on 32bit architecture and may be `8` on 64 bit architecture. You don't know. It may be `1` on a small 8-bit processor with very strange architecture.. , but I don't believe you will find such one today.

Comment: @KamilCuk, what do you mean? the pointer should change with realloc. I need to realloc in case the file I read has more bytes of data than I had anticipated, so I use total_menory to record that and double i_mem whenever it reaches the cap.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, ah I see. Just to be clear, when I allocate memory for the outside pointer, I need to allocate enough memory for the inside pointers, which could vary greatly, and keep track of it? In addition, I would have to add memory for the inside pointers, itself?

Comment: I think (if I get you correctly) yes. You are just doing a 2d array - you have an array of pointers and each of those pointers point to an array of characters. Your code looks very spagetti code, because the `ftell`/`fseek` are not really needed - you could just `realloc(dest[i]` after each character just add one character more to the space of each line. Try to refactor it to two function - one that reads one line and the other that reads multiple lines.

Comment: Try to use structures ex. `struct line_s { char *line; size_t length; }` and `struct text_s { struct line_s *lines; size_t count; }` instead of `***` stars. Then `realloc` will became simpler. `func(struct line_s *line) { line->line = realloc(line->line, line->length + 1);` etc.

Comment: In regards to the spagetti code, I remember reading online that reallocating just for each character seems to be very costly. I could be wrong though. Is that true?

Comment: This is in regards to a homework question, and I'm trying to make it run as efficiently as possible. The original question just asks us to allocate a huge space per word, and allocate a huge space for the list. So I haven't learned structures, unfortunately, and not for a while it appears :( Seems interesting, though! I'll take a look.

Comment: It is costly for some and some mature libraries realloc a little bit more then needed, for example the old version of [cs50 library multipled the capacity by 2](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/96d48593f149bb164d6c5bae15a7177f8f19a762/src/cs50.c#L142), rather then adding 1.

Comment: Oh also, not sure if you got this but ftell/fseek are used to determine the length of each line in the list from the file. I find the length of the line then allocate memory appropriately for it. I use realloc only when the outer pointer fills up and needs more space. I use the multiply capacity by 2 method when the outer pointer fills up (aka list)

Comment: I won't go anywhere without trying. Do you have any suggestions for this problem and what routes to take? I assume that this might be a relevant problem in general because this function consists of reading in a file and optimizing memory use for the allocation of the list into memory. Furthermore, I've completed the logistics of the problem; the only step now is to record it into memory. I suppose that there are much better and faster methods, for sure. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Geeze. A word of advice. Although comments can be really good, there are such a thing as "too much comments". Try to make the comments describe on a higher level and larger chunks of code. For instance, the comment `dest = realloc(dest, i_mem); /* allocate increased memory into dest */` is very unnecessary and just noise, because what it says is something that is exactly what the code itself without comments tell me.  Another completely unnecessary comment is this `read_mode = 1; /* go to read mode */`.

Comment: @klutt Hahah, thanks. Of course! But my teacher may be really picky and the last thing I want is to lose credit because of that. I understand everything fully so I'm essentially writing BS, which I suppose loses the purpose of the comments.

Me understanding it doesn't necessarily mean the teacher understanding that I understand it. They are concerned that people copy code.

Comment: @BONGER Yes, but you're posting on SO now. Please remove such noise when you post here because it's only confusing and it makes it harder to help you. And yes, you are perfectly correct that it loses the purpose. Tbh, commenting well is an art, and I don't think you should enforce commenting so much to early students, because it's always done wrong. Which is not strange, because commenting well is not trivial. A good example of that is that I have seen well commented code that has absolutely zero comments.

Comment: Preach. They haven't even said anything except "comment your code". No guidelines whatsoever, so I'm just commenting everything. I'm not sure if I'm understanding your last sentence correctly: are you saying some well commented code has no comments?

Comment: When it comes to commenting code, write exactly what is necessary to explain the code, and no more. Choose quality over quantity. I would penalise a student submitting over-commented code the same amount as for under-commenting. If you were a trainee chef, you would not be advised to skip the salt, but equally, don't just dump in the whole container!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you are setting a local variable, if you want to reflect the change to the variable passed as an argument you need an additional level of indirection, eg:

```
int read_list(char ***dest, char *file_name)
{
  ...
  *dest = realloc(...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ..
  read_list(&dict, ...);
}
```

This will make the change visible to the outside, otherwise only the local `dest` variable is changed.

Comment: On some more basic programs, I didn’t need to pass the address of these pointers and it still worked. Is it because I’m changing the address of the pointers using realloc? I also tried a more basic program for that too and it didn’t appear to be the case.

Comment: Yes, `realloc` (likely) changes the address so that the previous one is released.

Comment: If the addresses change, would I need to do any handling like using the free function? 

Also, I'm trying to implement the additional level of indirection now, but getting seg faults. I think it's just me, though, haha.